# Exceptions with parallel queries while running in OpenShift

Tags: spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, r2dbc-mssql

We're running a Spring Boot application with R2DBC MSSQL connection to an Azure SQL database. We addded a feature that basically does a `JOIN` in code (please disregard all performance issues here ;-)) and now we experience exceptions if this code is deployed to our OpenShift environment (If I run the same code on my machine everything is fine).

The exception is `org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: executeMany; SQL [SELECT * FROM equipment WHERE json_value(data, '$.installation.projectId') = @P0_synthetic0]; null` (Full StackTrace [here](https://gist.github.com/kschlesselmann/b486dd84aee6f7208c13a733f6998893)).

What I've found out so far is that the problematic code issues the queries in parallel like

```
findAllThings()
    .flatMap(lookupForOneThing)
    ...
```

if I change the code to work more sequential like

```
findAllThings()
    .collectList()
    .flatMapIterable(it)
    .flatMap(lookupForOneThing)
    ...
```

the error is gone in OpenShift as well.

Does anyone has an idea what's going on here?